# What are the balanced subsets of a scalar field?

Tags: functional-analysis

What are the balanced subsets of a scalar field?

In the proof if $\Lambda$ is continuous functional on a Topological vector space $X$ then it is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, Rudin chose a balanced subset $V$ of X and hence $\Lambda(V)$ is a balanced subset of the scalar field. Then he claimed it is either bounded or null set $\emptyset$.

Edit: I have understood that any bounded symmetric open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is balanced (symmetric in the sense $A=-A$). because if $x \in A$ then $(-1)x \in (-1)A \subset A$. any bounded open set is also balanced. Also $\mathbb{R}$ is balanced. I do not understand how did he claim if it is a balanced set in scalar field then it is either bounded or empty.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_set

Comment: I assume this is from _Functional Analysis_. Can you point is to where in the book this proof is so that we can see exactly what it is Rudin writes?

Comment: @Michael Yes this is from Rudin's $\textit{Functional Analysis}$ Page 15, Theorem 1.18. He stated it while proving (c) implies (d).

Comment: You've misread the proof. Rudin states that $\Lambda(V)$ is either bounded or the entire scalar field $\Phi$. The symbol $\Phi$ is different from the symbol $\emptyset$.

Comment: Ok, But can you please explain a bit how can I show that?

Answer (score 3):

A set $A$ in a $\mathbb K$-vector space $X$ (where $\mathbb K\in\{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$) is balanced if for every $a\in A$ and $t\in\mathbb K$ with $|t|\le 1$ one has $ta\in A$.

If now $A\subseteq \mathbb K$ is balanced and unbounded Rudin claims that $A= \mathbb K$. Indeed, given $z\in\mathbb K$ there is $a\in A$ with $|a|>|z|$ so that $t=z/a\in\mathbb K$ satisfies $|t|\le 1$ and $z=ta\in A$.

It might be a good exercise to describe all balanced subsets of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.

Comment: it is my intution that the balanced set of the scalar field will be connected also but i am not able to prove so. Any help?

Comment: Symmetric intervals.

Comment: that i understood but how to prove connectedness

Comment: You will find in many books on topology that arcwise connected sets are connected.